# Javascript: Problem with getting video duration when uploading multiple files

Tags: javascript, for-loop, video, onload, duration

I have a function that checks the duration of uploaded videos, but it only works when one file is uploaded. When I try to upload multiple files, the `video.duration` returns the correct value only for the first file, but for the others, it returns "NaN". Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is? Thank you.

```js
function CheckIfVideoDurationIsOk() {
   window.continueUpload = true;
   document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "";
   var ins = document.getElementById('multiFiles').files.length;
   for (var x = 0; x < ins; x++) {
      var video = document.createElement('video');
      video.preload = 'metadata';
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(document.getElementById('multiFiles').files[x]);
      console.log(x);
      video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
         window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
         console.log(video.duration);
         if (video.duration > 300) {
            window.continueUpload = false;
             $('#msg').html('<span>Video is too long</span>');
            return;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That's because its the common async problem here. You are resetting the video element even before it emits the `loadedmetadata` event, so only the last setting of the src will get its metadata loaded while being part of that video. Either you create a new video element every time, or you wrap it and await a Promise: `await const metadataLoadedEvent = new Promise(resolve =>  video.addEventListener( 'metadataloaded', resolve, { once: true })` and then continue from there.